# Can't install MS keyboard software due to company policy. Any alternatives?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, installation

I bought a Microsoft desktop set for my desk at work. The keyboard and mouse work but I can't install the supplied IntelliType Pro software to make use of the media keys (e.g. assign favourite programs to run).

Any alternatives or ways to bypass the installer so I can re-assign these keys?

Comment: whoa, such a strict company policy that disallows actual genuine keyboard's. Too strict IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of because it requires a driver. but, unless you know you are going to use it, I wouldn't bother looking for alternatives.

Nearly everyone I know with multimedia type keyboards use the keys within the first week as they are cool or new, but then just forget about them or do not use them.

Personally, on mine, I use volume up/down/mute which does not require any drivers, but that is it!

Comment: The shortcuts to launch apps are quite useful. I know most people don't use them but once you get used to them it's hard to go back!

Answer (score 1):

What about manually extracting the driver files and placing them into the system directory?  When I worked for the county everything was blocked, installers etc (even web browsers) but for some strange reason we had write access to system and system32.

Also, if that doesn't work you can trick the installer into running as system with the at command (make a batch file in notepad).

use the at command (just schedule it like 1 min into the future)  [Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565)  because anything it executes forks off of system and has 'root' privileges.

This works for gaining a CMD window with admin access as well

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for not being able to install IntelliType Pro, except if you have the wrong installer. For example, you might be trying to install 32bits drivers on 64bits Windows.

I suggest that you download the latest IntelliType Pro version from Microsoft at:
[Download Mouse and Keyboard Software](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx?category=mk)
and try again.

**EDIT**

If group policies are blocking the installation, here are two ways to bypass them (not tested by myself):

- Remove the ethernet
  cable from the computer immediately after logging in
  (i.e. as soon as credentials are accepted) to block GPs
  from being downloaded/applied. [Source](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/88/388591/2005-01-22/2005-01-28/0).
- [Disabling Group Policy restrictions through the registry](http://www.msfn.org/board/lofiversion/index.php/t85346.html)

Comment: he did not say that it doesn't work - he said that due to group policy, he can't install it.

Comment: See my edit. . .

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth contacting your IT department and just asking them to install the drivers for you. The IntelliType drivers are pretty benign stuff, and come in a nice MSI package which your IT dept shouldn't have any huge problems with installing for you if they're at all reasonable.